# Question about a proof regarding stopping times and the event $\{T<t\}$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a complete probability space with filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{0\leqslant t\leqslant \infty}$ such that $\mathcal F_0$ contains all the $\mathbb P$-null sets of $\mathcal F$ and the filtration is right-continuous, i.e. $\mathcal F_t = \bigcap_{u>t}\mathcal F_u$.  It is claimed that

> The event $\{T<t\}\in\mathcal F_t$ if and only if $T$ is a stopping time.

The proof is as follows: Since $\{T\leqslant t\}=\bigcap_{t+\varepsilon>u>t}\{T<u\}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\{T\leqslant T\}\in\bigcap_{u>t} \mathcal F_u = \mathcal F_t$, so $T$ is a stopping time. (This part I am fine with.)

My question is about the converse. It is claimed that $\{T<t\}=\bigcup_{t>\varepsilon>0}\{T\leqslant t-\varepsilon\}$, and $\{T\leqslant t-\varepsilon\}\in\mathcal F_{t-\varepsilon}$, hence also in $\mathcal F_t$.

But $\bigcup_{t>\varepsilon>0}\{T\leqslant t-\varepsilon\}$ is an uncountable union of events. Shouldn't we instead consider a sequence of rational numbers $r_n>0$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} r_n=0$ and $\bigcup_{t>r_n>0}\{T\leqslant t-r_n\}$?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to consider the values $\epsilon =\frac  1 n$: $T<t$ iff there exists $n$ such that $T \leq t-\frac  1n$.

Comment: So $$\{T<t\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{T\leqslant t-\frac 1n\right\}\in \mathcal F_{t-\frac1n}$$ is therefore a countable union of events?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, you are right.

Comment: I suppose more precisely I should write $$ \{T<t\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{T\leqslant t-\frac1n\right\}$$ where $\{T\leqslant t-\frac1n\}\in\mathcal F_{t-\frac1n}$ for positive integers $n$.

Comment: And that $\{t\leqslant t-\frac1n\}=\{t\leqslant 0\}$ for $0\leqslant t\leqslant 1$.

Comment: $\{t: t \leq t-\frac  1n\}$ is the empty set. @Math1000

Comment: Ah right, since presumably $t\in[0,\infty)$ to begin with.